# PrintDocument.Print results in Win32Exception The operation completed successfully

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print in a C# .NET 3.5 app to a network printer and getting this exception:

> The operation completed successfully

What is causing it, and how can it be solved?

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal()
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(PageSettings pageSettings)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
```

- the account has permissions to print using the network printer. The permissions are set for Everyone to print.
- the printer has been deleted and recreated.
- the setting for spooling vs printing directly to the printer has been toggled both ways.
- other printers on the machine work fine
- other clients on the network and apps on this same machine can print to this printer without issue.

To narrow the issue down, I've created a simple console app. Running as a normal user, the app prints. When Run As the service account, it errs **for the service account**.

[image]

The **resolution** to my problem was to uninstall the driver that is causing the issue, and install an older driver.

Comment: I've gotten this error before - the error message is really misleading. I figure you have this finished, but if you don't post some code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @p.campbell sorry I don't. I remember lack of documentation on these topics to be extremely frustrating, so sorry I couldn't be of more help. I have a couple of old questions I posted at the time on semi-related printing topics, not sure if those will be relevant or not or if you already checked them out though.

Answer (score 22):

The mystifying message is caused by a bug in pinvoke code inside the .NET Framework.  The underlying winapi call that fails is the [`DocumentProperties()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The pinvoke declaration for it looks like this:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int DocumentProperties(...);
```

The `SetLastError` property is wrong.  As you can tell from the MSDN link, the function indicates failure by returning a negative value.  And is *not* documented to set the error code that's returned by `GetLastError()`.

The consequence of this bug is that the framework will call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to obtain the error code and will get a random value since `DocumentProperties()` didn't set it.  A value of `0` is not unlikely,  which produces the "The operation completed successfully" exception message.

So you need to ignore the exception message; it is very unhelpful of course.  Unfortunately, this winapi function falls into a category of functions, like most GDI functions do, that only produce an "it didn't work" return code.  It gives no hint where to look for the problem.  There is a half-decent reason for this quirk: Windows itself does very little when you call `DocumentProperties()`; most of the work is done by the printer driver.  There is no set of error codes set-aside for printing in the winapi.  Anything is possible: printer drivers are not subtle chunks of code.  It is the job of the printer driver to tell you about problems. They are supposed to do so by popping up their own window.  Theoretically they are anyway; the cut-throat competition in that market segment does not leave a lot of money to pay a good programmer's salary these days.

This of course cannot work when you print from a service.  There isn't any way to see such a popup window, which is the core reason that Microsoft **strongly** discourages printing from a service.  Neither you nor your customer's IT staff stands a chance to diagnose problems.  Read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/06/24/printing-from-a-windows-service.aspx) for additional notes about using `PrintDocument` from a service.

Nobody likes to get advice like this, but the writing is on the wall.  *Don't do it*.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @HansPassant's answer, here is the exact code in question that throws the exception:

Microsoft Reference Source, [PrinterSettings.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PrinterSettings.cs.html)

```
private IntPtr GetHdevmodeInternal(string printer) {
    // Create DEVMODE
    int modeSize = SafeNativeMethods.DocumentProperties(NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, printer, IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, 0);
    if (modeSize < 1) {
        throw new InvalidPrinterException(this);
    }
    IntPtr handle = SafeNativeMethods.GlobalAlloc(SafeNativeMethods.GMEM_MOVEABLE, (uint)modeSize); // cannot be <0 anyway
    IntPtr pointer = SafeNativeMethods.GlobalLock(new HandleRef(null, handle));

    //Get the DevMode only if its not cached....
    if (cachedDevmode != null) {
        Marshal.Copy(cachedDevmode, 0, pointer, devmodebytes);
    }
    else  {
        int returnCode = SafeNativeMethods.DocumentProperties(NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, printer, pointer, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, SafeNativeMethods.DM_OUT_BUFFER);
        if (returnCode < 0) {
            throw new Win32Exception();  // <--------
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. In my case, I used a separate Thread to print the report, and synchronized it with the Main Thread via "ManualResetEvent". (I have developed this way because the .Net forces divide the print logic into the "PrintPage" methods...).

The error happens due to an incompatibility (which I can not explain the source) between the printer driver and this multi-threaded environment.

I solved the problem by changing my print logic method signature from "void" to "IEnumerable", and break through yield return, a method similar to the "CoRoutines" of the Unity3d gaming engine. This way, it is not necessary to create more than one thread, and my print code gets organized.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but you just helped me fix an issue i was working on for days. 
For testing purposes, i launched my print on the UI thread and it did work, returned to launching the print from another thread and updated the printer's driver to the latest official release from HP and it works now. 
I was using HP's universal PCL6 6.2.6 before. That driver doesn't like being called in a multithreaded environement.

Comment: 6.2.1, sorry.
HP Universal Printing PCL 6 (v6.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to answer with no code and an exception that says you everything is OK. So I'll just give a few ideas to track down the problem

1. Test it on a local printer to make sure the application works.
2. Try printing to the networked printer using notepad or something similar
3. Double nay triple check that the user the application is running as has permissions to print to the network printer.
4. Test it on another networked printer (after doing 2 and 3 for that printer)